# Treble clef instead of bass clef even though there are low sounds

Tags: piano

I don't know what this means[image: I don'y know what this means]

Even though the treble clef is on the second row I play it with the left hand and why is the bass clef at the end?

This is a new song  I try to learn and I'm really confused about the clefs
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clef doesn't necessarily mean to tell you which hand to play with. It's there to make the music easy to play, compared with putting the notes on ledger lines. The bottom of the two staves is for your left hand to play. Just read it as if it's the notes you are used to playing with your right hand, except you play those with your left. When it goes back to bass clef, everything is normal again. The clef sign at the end of a line is to warn you that there's going to be a clef change, otherwise you'd be reading notes on lots of ledger lines and that's not easy.

Comment: so on the new song, on the second stave, the one with 2 treble clefs , the first note i play is the B just before the middle C?

Comment: On the new song, where there's a change to treble clef, you'll play the minims C-Cb-Bb with l.h. By the way, Cb=B.

Comment: i don't really understand i'm european and I use Do Re and so on

Comment: so it would be RE then 2x RE-FA in the first measure

Comment: European doesn't help! If you use FIXED do, then the l.h. notes are Do, Si, Si bemol. In French. But the notes still remain called C, Cb, Bb. If you use MOVABLE do, assuming it's in Bb, it'll be Re, Re flat, Do for the minims.Fa and La are the crotchets.Making a triad of Cm root position in bar 5 of the new song (C-Eb-G).

Answer (score 0):

In two-stave keyboard music, the RH generally plays the upper STAVE, LH the lower.  It's quite possible for the music to be all above middle C, thus making treble clef appropriate for both hands.  Similarly for music all below middle C and bass clef.

The bass clef at the end of the line is a warning that the LH is about to return to bass clef.

Though we sometimes loosely refer to treble clef as "the RH clef", this isn't strictly true.  And, despite what I said above, it isn't ALWAYS "RH upper stave, LH lower stave".